# Why are word (.docx) email attachments converted to .dat files in HCL Domino 11

Tags: email, ibm-domino

We are running HCL Domino 11.0

Sometimes when users receive emails from external senders. Then email attachments are changed to .dat files with a format like this att*.dat. It seems to happens for Word and Excel files.

Not all attachments are changed. It only happens in a few cases. I have not found any pattern for when it happens.

Last case I have seen was an email with two attachments a word file and an Excel file. Only the word file was converted to .dat. Filename are "att6bm22.dat" and "Annex 1 - Prices.xlsx"

.dat files can still be opened in for example Word.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Why do you think the problem is at your end? It's almost certain that these emails were in this condition before you received them.

Comment: @MichaelHampton no I'm not sure it is even at my end. I have search a lot on this subject. And I have seen some indication that it could be an Outlook issue. But I haven't found anything concrete. It could also be a combination of both sender service and Domino.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe a regression issue.  I have seen this in the past but it was related to calendar invites from Outlook to Domino.  The resolution to that was to add TNEFENABLECONVERSION=1 to the Notes.ini file in Domino. I am currently having this issue as well except mine has to do with .xls files.  It was also stated from, back then, IBM support if the outlook user had the receiver in their contact list and send out an email with a microsoft app file this would cause the issue.  Domino has changed now so not sure if this is still the issue.

Comment: My Domino administrator have investigated this a bit more. We already have tnefenableconversion=1 enabled on the server. He also checked with HCL and it looks it is a know error. So I guess we just have to wait for a fix.